# How to find the index of a value in a list that is closest to the beginning or end of the list?

Tags: python

How to find the index of a particular value in a list that is closest to the beginning or end of the list?
So far I have only output a list of values. But how do I find the index that is closest to the beginning or end of the list.

```
└─$ cat /home/david/Документы/test/test.py
a='0'
b=input().split()
#b='4 1 5 5 6 2 3 1 6 1 4 3 0 6 0 4'
#print(a)
#print(b)
print(b[:len(b)//2])
print(b[len(b)//2:])
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    #print(i,b[i])
    #if a in b:
    if a in b[len(b)//2:]:
        #print(i,b[i])
        #b[:len(b)//2]
        print(i,b[i])
    else:
        print(-1)
        break 
└─$ /bin/python3.11 /home/david/Документы/test/test.py
4 1 5 5 6 2 3 1 6 1 4 3 0 6 0 4
['4', '1', '5', '5', '6', '2', '3', '1']
['6', '1', '4', '3', '0', '6', '0', '4']
0 4
1 1
2 5
3 5
4 6
5 2
6 3
7 1
8 6
9 1
10 4
11 3
12 0
13 6
14 0
15 4
```

For example, at the input of such a list of numbers:

> 4 1 5 5 6 2 3 1 6 1 4 3 0 6 0 4

the result for the value "0" will be 14, since the closest index of the value "0" to the end is 14.

Among all the occurrences of an item in the list, find the one that is closest to the beginning or end of the list. If the desired occurrence is equidistant from the beginning and end, output the index that is closer to the beginning. If the item is not in the list, print -1. Two lines are submitted to the program for input. The first line contains the number whose index you need to find, the second line contains a list of numbers separated by spaces.

What algorithm should I use? How can lambda be used? and is it necessary to use it here?

Comment: Please provide a better and more structured explanation of the problem, I really cannot understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish or what the problem is, how would the result be 14? what is 14?

Comment: Are you looking for the index *at which a specific, given number* occurs in a list closest to the list's start/end?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this was my understanding (the title is more explicit)

Comment: It’s nice that you folks guess what the question is supposed to be, but it would be even nicer if the asker actually clarified. The initial description does *not* match the new one.

Comment: Here the correct answer is 14, because this is the index of the element "0". the closest item in the list is in the 14th index at the end of the list.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the initial description had some slight grammatical errors. That's not the same thing as asking a different question. The initial question included the line of code `a='0'` which clarified what was being asked, it was just a bit "hidden".

Comment: @DanGetz Since the code doesn’t do what they want, singling out one feature that was actively contradicted by the description seems…dubious. Alas, since the new description hasn’t been rolled back over multiple edits it appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the positions to the middle of the list and get the max absolute value:

```
half = (len(b)-1)/2
-max((abs(i-half), -i) for i, x in enumerate(b) if x == a)[1]
```

Output: `14`

The use of `-i` is to ensure having the value closest to the beginning in case of a tie.

Reproducible input:

```
s = '4 1 5 5 6 2 3 1 6 1 4 3 0 6 0 4'
a = '0'
b = s.split()
```

Other input/outputs:

```
# input:  0 4 0
# output: 0 

# input:  0 1 4 0
# output: 0

# input:  1 0 4 0
# output: 3

# input:  1 2 0 3 4
# output: 2
```